# How to restrict the unauthorized software download

Tags: plugins

I have developed one software and creating one wordpress website so that people can download it. People needs to make the payment through gateway and then download it. But how can I restrict the unauthorized downloads? Suppose one person makes the payment, gets the download link and then shares the download link to someone else who didn't make the payment. How can I restrict the download for that user?

What are the different approaches to solve this problem? Is there any plugin for this?

Thanks
Nirmalya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict unauthorized software downloads on your WordPress website, you can implement the following approaches:

1. **Membership/Subscription System**: You can use a membership or subscription plugin to control access to your downloads. Users must create an account and pay for a subscription to access the download links. This way, you can track who has paid and limit access to authorized users only. Some popular plugins for this purpose include [MemberPress](https://memberpress.com/), [Restrict Content Pro](https://restrictcontentpro.com/), or [WooCommerce Memberships](https://woo.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/).
2. **Unique Download Links**: Generate unique download links for each purchase. When a user makes a payment, generate a one-time or time-limited download link tied to their purchase. This prevents sharing since the link will expire or can only be used once. E-commerce plugins like WooCommerce can be customized to implement this feature.
3. **License Keys**: Issue license keys with each purchase and require users to activate the software using their unique key. This way, even if someone shares the download link, the software won't work without a valid key. You can use plugins like [Easy Digital Downloads (EDD)](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/) along with [EDD Software Licensing](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/downloads/software-licensing/) to manage this.
4. **IP/Session Tracking**: Implement IP or session tracking to limit downloads from multiple IP addresses or sessions for a single purchase. This method can deter unauthorized sharing to some extent, but it may inconvenience legitimate users who share a network or use VPNs.
5. **Anti-Piracy Services**: Consider using anti-piracy services like DMCA takedown requests to protect your software. These services can help in identifying and taking down unauthorized copies of your software on the internet.
6. **Digital Rights Management (DRM)**: Implement DRM technologies if your software allows it. DRM can prevent unauthorized access and sharing, but it can also be complex and may not be suitable for all types of software.
7. **Legal Agreements**: Include clear terms of service and licensing agreements on your website. This can serve as a legal deterrent against unauthorized sharing.

There isn't a single plugin that covers all these aspects, but you can combine various plugins and custom development to create a robust solution based on your specific needs.

Remember to regularly update your methods to stay ahead of potential pirates, as determined individuals may still find ways to share your software.

Comment: Hi Will, thank you so much for the detailed answer. Much appreciated :-)